# packet capture for communication between 2 pods on K8 cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes, flannel

I am testing K8 cluster setup and trying to understand the networking between 2 pods. The K8 is using the flannel as its CNI. The communication is happening correctly, but i would like to analyze a bit on the packet flow.

I tried to capture the packets on the flannel interface and the veth interfaces that is created but no luck.

I captured the packets on cni0 that is created by K8 but i am only able to see the application layer i.e either TCP 3 way handshake or the HTTP messages..

What is the procedure to capture the packet to view the overlay packets?

Answer (score 0):

How about using wireshark and capturing on the "physical" interface of your machines. Every packet will go through there ultimately, so you should be able to see VXLAN packets on that interface.

Comment: Not sure if it does. VXLAN packets are stripped off before they are actually delivered. So far i have been trying this communication within one machine. Will try across the machines..